# Using IOKit from within an iOS 7 application?

Tags: ios7, usb, iokit

Can IOKit be used for USB communication when running on an iOS7 based device or is it limited to OS X only?

Comment: My understanding is that you can use (parts of) IOKit on iOS if you won't be submitting the app to the App Store. So that limits you to Enterprise or Ad Hoc distribution. The other option is joining Apple's MFI (Made for i…) programme, which will allow you to submit apps that communicate with peripherals to the App Store. There is not much public information on the latter.